# React Native Web crashes with aws-amplify

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm using aws-amplify in my app for iOS, Android and Web, but when I import aws-amplify

```
import 'aws-amplify';
```

Android and iOS work fine but the web app crashes with the error message:

```
Failed to compile
Can't reexport the named export 'BREAK' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: In early '21, I'm experiencing a similar problem.  Although my logs are showing that the issue is in node_modules/graphql/index.mjs - which is imported with aws-amplify.  I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Me too! Anyone found a solution or the core of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for your web app client you should be importing like this:

`import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';`

Comment: Same error. As soon as I import something from aws-amplify or aws-amplify as a whole the error occurs.
(I was using it your way anyway, just wanted to provide a minimal example)

Comment: @GabrielWinkler it looks like there's an issue open regarding this exact issue. You may want to  comment there and +1 the issue so the Amplify team prioritize this. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4299